# Merging multiple .db files - Ubuntu

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a number of `.db` files that I'd like to merge into one.
Each database has four tables.

- 'Associated'
- 'Candidate'
- 'Picks'
- 'Picks_modified'

The tables might be empty in some of the files. I would like to merge these files using python2.7.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Antoine

Answer (score 1):

This is a general SQLite solution which should work for you in Python as well.  Assuming you had three databases, and you wanted the contents of the second and third tables in the tables of the first database, then you could try this:

```
ATTACH 'database1.db' AS db1;
ATTACH 'database2.db' AS db2;
ATTACH 'database3.db' AS db3;

INSERT INTO db1.Associated
SELECT * FROM db2.Associated
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db3.Associated
UNION ALL
...
```

Repeat the above for the other three tables in your databases (`Candidate`, `Picks`, `Picks_modified`).

In other words, we can insert the records from the other databases into the tables of the first database.  If you wanted to aggregate everything in a different, perhaps new, database, then you can easily modfiy the above code to handle this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer Tim, I'm gonna try that now !

Comment: If I understand well, "table1" should be replace with "picks" by example in my case ?
Because when running it using python2.7, I get : "OperationalError: near "picks": syntax error"
I am a novice in SQLite, I must admit.

Comment: @AntoineHaddad I tried to update my answer to be more specific.